# Django Custom Filter to get video duration using MoviePy not working

Tags: python, django, moviepy

I am trying to use a custom filter to find the video duration using moviepy however the function is not able to access the files even though it seems the correct video path is being passed into the function in the custom filter.

I'm getting the following error:

```
OSError at /tape/tape/
MoviePy error: the file /media/video_files/channel_Busy/171003B_026_2k.mp4 could not be found!
Please check that you entered the correct path.
```

The custom filter:

vduration.py

```
from django import template
import moviepy.editor
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='vduration')
def vduration(videourl):
    
    video = moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip(videourl)
    video_time = int(video.duration)
    return video_time
```

views.py

```
def tape(request):
    tapes=VideoFiles.objects.all()
    context={
        "videos": tapes,
    }
    return render(request, "tape/tape.html", context)
```

tape.py

```
{% for video in videos %}
  <div class="video-time">{{video.video.url | vduration}}</div>
 {% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class VideoFiles(models.Model):
    id=models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    video=models.FileField(upload_to=channel_directory_path)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('video_watch', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return f"video_file_{self.id}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the absolute path of the `media` file.

**vduration.py**

```
import os
from django import template
import moviepy.editor
from your.settings.file import BASE_DIR 

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='vduration')
def vduration(videourl):
    
    video = moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, videourl))
    video_time = int(video.duration)
    return video_time
```

Comment: It seems BASE_DIR is only returning "C:/" and concatenating the relative part of the video URL instead e.g C:/media/video_files/channel_Busy/171003B_026_2k.mp when the actual absolute path is C:/Users/User/Desktop/Site/media/video_files/channel_Busy171003B_026_2k.mp4. Only concatenating ("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Site" + videourl) has worked but I do not want to hardwire this. Any ideas?

Comment: in your `settings.py` do you have this line `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

Comment: no but in the pre written code it came as `BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent` instead.

Comment: Add it to your `settings.py` under another variable name and use it in your filter. `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))` will give you `C:/Users/User/Desktop/Site`

Comment: I Don't know what I'm doing wrong but still getting the same result